# Xamarin GoogleMaps custom renderer in iOS -> NPE

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm writing a project with a pcl and ios components. I'm following this sample:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/CustomRenderers/Map/Pin

Using it in conjunction with Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps NuGet package.

I'm facing a problem inside iOS renderer, because on row number 37 https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/CustomRenderers/Map/Pin/iOS/CustomMapRenderer.cs#L37 i will get always

`var nativeMap = null`

I can't understand what I'm missing

EDIT:
Debugging I get some more information. The problem seems to be `Control as MKMapView` casting, infact that casting returns null, Control seems to be GMSMapView type instead of MKMapView.

How to go ahead of this problem???

Comment: `MKMapView` is Apple maps and `GMSMapView` is Google's map view on iOS. Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps NuGet package would be `GMSMapView`-based, not `MKMapView`, the renderer you reference is `MKMapView` based, you are mixing the two and that will not work.

Comment: Ok, it's what I was supposing... Do you know where i can find some documentation or sample to customize a GMSMapView based iOS renderer?

Comment: You could always just use the 3rd-party source from https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps. or create an iOS project and implement `Google.Maps.MapView` via the "official" Google Map API wrapper (`Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps`) and one you have figured out your custom implementation needs, port that to a Forms-based renderer.